AWS DMS "Load complete, replication ongoing" not working MongoDB to DocumentDB

I wanted to migrate data from mongo db ec2 instance to document db - )

Mongo db as a service is using ec2 instance -

Same ec2 machine I have attached with document db.

Mongo shell and db version ( 4.4.17 )

I have already created end points source and target and tested successfully.

DMS Replication instances has been created.


In Database migration tasks I am using task.
AWS DMS Status:
Load complete, replication ongoing.
However data is not getting replicated / migrated on target Document DB . After several minutes has been passed.
Can any one help?

I have created replica set () in mongod conf. The failure error has been removed.
The below issue didn't resolve the issue.
db.adminCommand({modifyChangeStreams: 1,
database: "db_name",
collection: "",
enable: true});

Cloudwatch logs.

Are there any errors in the CloudWatch logs? You can search for error using this pattern: "]E"

This is resolved by checking the error logs from cloud watch.
